# howto: optional (nested) class property?

Tags: interface, typescript

I have a class which I want to have some optional nested properties.

```
class Input {
    stuff {
        first_name?: string;   // optional
    };
```

however it seems that isn't legal typescript. `; expected`

Next is to pull stuff out into an interface

```
interface IFrom {
    id: any;
    first_name?: string;
};

class Input {
    from:IFrom;
```

however when i put these in the same file I get

`tsPublic property 'from' of exported class has or is using private name 'IFrom'.`

I can't make `public interface`

```
'public' modifier cannot appear on a module element.
```

What I've ended up doing is putting the interface in yet another file, but this is getting to be astronaut engineering where every struct and property needs to be in its own file...

Am I missing something about how best to do this? 
I want the first_name property to be public but part of a struct.
Want it to be optional.
Prefer fewer individual files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> however it seems that isn't legal typescript. ; expected

The syntax for *inline* types is incorrect. You are missing a `:`. The following works fine:

```
class Input {
    stuff: {
        first_name?: string;   // optional
    };
}
```

## That answers the question. But since you tried more stuff:

> Public property 'from' of exported class has or is using private name 'IFrom'.

You probably have `export class` ... that means that you need to do `export interface` *too* to export any interface that the class uses.

Comment: thanks for the comments and picking up my silly mistake!

Comment: update: I can't use export interface if I already have `export = ClassX` in the same file... which is a bit of hassle.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the keyword `export` with interfaces and classes, not `public`.

Here is an example:

```
module ModuleA {
  export interface IFrom {
      id: any;
      first_name?: string;
  }
}

module ModuleB {
  export class Input {
      from:ModuleA.IFrom;
  } 
}

var input = new ModuleB.Input();

input.from = {id: 123, first_name: 'Bob'};

alert(input.from.first_name); // Bob
```

Comment: got it. and thanks for the clear example. however i was trying to avoid using modules...